# Will upgrading to Yosemite remove all my tweaks and setting?

Tags: macos, upgrade

I've made many small tweaks and preference customization to the Mavericks install on my Mac. If I upgrade to Yosemite, will those tweaks and preferences be reset and would require me to re-apply them?

Comment: Can you give us examples of Your "tweaks"? Are You storing anything inside `/System` dir?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I upgraded from Mavericks to Yosemite several months ago, and didn't notice any differences with OS preferences.  They should stay the same. However some application specific preferences may change, but I would guess that for most standard apps, like Mail, your preferences would remain intact.  But it would help if you were more specific about what kind of preferences.

Answer (score 1):

In general, no. Most of your settings will remain intact, but some of them may be reset or irrelevant in Yosemite.